# how to run different `MLproject` files from the main directory with mlflow?

Tags: python, mlflow

Is it possible to have multiple projects and running any of them from the main directory by specifying which one to run at run time?

I don't see an option to specify the project file in the command line interface `mlflow run`

Answer (score 0):

If you have your project hosted in [GitHub](https://github.com) (which is always advised and recommended) or any other version control hub, you should be able to run your project as follows:

```bash
mlflow run git@github.com:<user>/<repository>.git -P <param1>=<value>
```